# Did not open any of any email in the last 6 months - 30 min , Query Failed - TimeOut

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query, subscriber, activity

Query:

```
SELECT 
s.SubscriberKey
,s.SubscriberID
, s.JobId
, s.EventDate AS 'Sent Date'
,sub.EmailAddress
,s.OYBAccountID As 'AccountID'
,'False' AS Not_Opened 
FROM _sent s 
INNER JOIN _Subscribers sub 
ON s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey 
where (
     s.SubscriberKey IS NOT NULL 
     AND s.SubscriberKey NOT IN 
        ( SELECT o.SubscriberKey 
            FROM _Open o 
                WHERE o.JobID = s.JobID 
                    AND o.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey) )
```

I want to get who did not open any of emails in the last 6 months or more.It is not for any specific jobId..

I am getting same time out 30 min error. I split below query in 2 parts.Firstly I fetch the sent data and after that run the another query on sent data extension to get who did not open any of emails data but still getting the same error.

Comment: Query:SELECT s.SubscriberKey,s.SubscriberID, s.JobId, s.EventDate AS 'Sent Date',sub.EmailAddress,s.OYBAccountID As 'AccountID','False' AS Not_Opened
from _sent s
INNER JOIN _Subscribers sub
ON s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey
where (

    s.SubscriberKey IS NOT NULL
AND
    s.SubscriberKey NOT IN (
      SELECT o.SubscriberKey 
      FROM _Open o  
      WHERE o.JobID = s.JobID
      AND 
        o.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey)
  
)

Comment: How many subscribers are we talking?  If it is a significant size, you will need to break the query up into multiple parts to account for processing time. I see you stated you already tried breaking it into 2 - can you post those queries as well?

Comment: your Where with a third lookup into _Open is likely causing issues as that will need to run on every single entry of your query. This will greatly slow down your query.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a significant amount of subscribers, I broke this into two queries.

I am sure there are many other SQL experts that could likely make this even better, but I think this should get the job done for you.

YOUR DE: (NO_OPEN_6months)

```
SubscriberKey  |  JobID  |  SubscriberID  |  EmailAddress  |  Sent Date  |  AccountID  |  Not_Opened
```

I would recommend having SubscriberKey and JobID as Primary Keys

SQL QUERY 1:

```
SELECT 
s.SubscriberKey
, s.SubscriberID
, s.JobId
, s.EventDate AS [Sent Date]
,s.OYBAccountID As AccountID
,'False' AS Not_Opened 
FROM _sent s
LEFT JOIN
_Open o
ON o.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE o.SubscriberKey IS NULL
```

**TO:** NO_OPEN_6months
**Update Type:** Overwrite

SQL QUERY 2:

```
SELECT 
sub.EmailAddress, op.SubscriberKey, op.JobID
FROM _Subscribers sub
LEFT JOIN
NO_OPEN_6months op
ON op.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey
WHERE sub.SubscriberKey IN (SELECT SubscriberKey FROM NO_OPEN_6months)
```

**TO:** NO_OPEN_6months
**Update Type:** Update

The first query will do the bulk of the work, getting all of your fields except EmailAddress.  I set this to Overwrite to make sure it only retains the last 6 months of data.

The second query will pull the EmailAddress from Subscirbers DataView and then Update your DE with it based on matching the SubscriberKeys.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington I tried your approach. In query 1, I get an error. Looks like it needs "FULL OUTER JOIN" instead of "Outer Join" and I am not able. With your query#1 with simple "outer join", I get error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'." In addition to this, in query#2 on saving throws an error that target data extension needs JobID. Since SubscriberKey and JobID are marked as Primary Keys they need value so i am not able to save query#2 at all.

Comment: I have now updated the SQL to be fully functional. I ran it through on a test audience of around 2.5mil records to ensure it wasn't too heavy.

Comment: Thank you @Gortonington for the update. How can i limit the results to our business unit only? Our BU is a sub-business unit (NOT parent account) but i think data views hold all records from all accounts / business units. How can i get results from our BU ONLY?

Comment: You should be able to add in a clause based on AccountID - e.g. `WHERE s.AccountID = '1234567'` which will limit the results to only that BU

Comment: I am trying to understand your approach. The data view only keeps 6 months of data. If we want subscribers who did not open emails for 6 months then shouldn't we try this approach? `SELECT DISTINCT s.SubscriberID, s.SubscriberKey, sub.EmailAddress, s.EventDate, s.AccountID FROM _Sent s WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN _Subscribers sub
ON s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,s.EventDate,GETDATE()) > 180 AND s.SubscriberID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SubscriberID FROM _open) AND 
s.SubscriberID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SubscriberID FROM _click) AND s.AccountID = 'XXXXXX'`

Comment: If you want to have an overview of not opening ANY emails, you can take jobID out of the DE and the queries. This will base it solely on matching the SubscriberKey as UID.